# Are open liquids always colder than ambient temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, liquid-state

I recently got myself a cheap thermal camera, and amongst other things I also noticed that standing water, even if it has been out for several days, always appears ~2°C colder than ambient temperature.

I intuitively explain it by assuming that even below the boiling point there is some degree of evaporation going on. After all, how else would e.g. spilled water dry up on its own.

Which makes me wonder, is this a general rule that is true for all liquids in all environments? Will any open standing liquid after a sufficient amount of time always be just a tad cooler than its surroundings?

Comment: To test the evaporation theory, try placing a bowl of liquid in a closed chamber where there humidity is 100%. This will prevent any further evaporation events.

Comment: Search for `desert water bags` to learn about a device that uses this mechanism to provide pleasantly cool drinking water. Also see [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/97959/how-does-a-canvas-water-bag-cool-water/99301).

Answer (score 1):

No. It depends crucially on ventilation to remove the build-up of water vapour. As @Steeven says, try it in a closed container (and consider the second law of thermodynamics).

Comment: By "open" I meant "not closed" aka no closed container. Guess I could have been more clear. Anyway it's pretty obvious that in a closed container no (continous) evaporation will occur, don't see a need to test this.